# Is it already possible to use top-level await in react-native?

Tags: typescript, react-native, async-await, babeljs, metro-bundler

Is it already possible to use top-level await in react-native? I saw it's been added to TypeScript 3.8 (I was not using TS, I just tried to see if it would help but no). However in react-native file transform is handled by babel and I don't think the current metro preset handles top-level awaits. Is there any way to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

ECMAScript feature top-level await stands on two conditions:

1. ES2017+
2. ECMAScript native modules (they are compiled to functions)

But React-Native uses node modules, so the answer is **no**.

See [Ecma international standard](https://tc39.es/proposal-top-level-await/) for more

**EDIT**:

According to comment and [more](https://dev.to/mikeesto/top-level-await-in-node-2jad) is possible in Node.js. But React-Native uses V8, [which supports it too](https://v8.dev/features/top-level-await). It just compiles JSX to C++.

Comment: It seems there is node support now. https://www.stefanjudis.com/today-i-learned/top-level-await-is-available-in-node-js-modules/ But I can't figure out how to get it working with react native. Would you mind editing your answer to show how if you know?

Comment: @QrowSaki Did you ever find out how to enable it? I can't get it to work in a stock react native app at all.

Comment: @bleeckerj I think you need dynamic import("..") to make module a promise

Comment: @TomášWróbel Thank you — can you elaborate or provide a pointer to a more detailed explanation? I'm still mystified. Although I can get it to work in one configuration that's quite simple, but not other similar ones. I don't know what is "turning it on" at all. (cf https://github.com/fireship-io/web3-nft-dapp-tutorial/blob/main/package.json)